# Xamarin MVVM update list from other Viewmodel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm

I am working in Xamarin Cross Platform
android
I have 2 Viewmodels
-MyTeamVM
-CertificatesVM

MyTeamVm is a listview where i can click on a person. Once i have clicked i go to CertificatesVM where i will see the certificates of the clicked person.
 The problem is the first time when i click on person everything works fine because the program go to :(this is in certificatesVM)

```
protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            var user = _userDataService.GetSelectedUser();
            Certificates = (await _earnedCertificateDataService.GetCertificateForUserAsync(user.Id));
        }
```

But when i go back to MyTeamView and choose an other person he doesn't update the list. I Have a

```
public MvxCommand ReloadCertificates
        {
            get
            {
                return new MvxCommand(async () =>
                {
                    var user = _userDataService.GetSelectedUser();
                    Certificates = (await _earnedCertificateDataService.GetCertificateForUserAsync(user.Id));
                });
            }
        }
```

but it does not work.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MessagingCenter** for call other viewModel list

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Comment: I am Using Xamarin native and use it in my viewmodel but i have the error : the name messagingCenter does not exist.
Do i need to add a reference or something?